# Split a string into two using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this `132+456` or `132-456` or `132*456`..etc ,it changes dynamically but I need to split this into `132` and `456` how to do it using pure java script?

Comment: `'132+456'.split('+')`

Comment: how to store it into two different var? it returns `132,456`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as easy as:

```
var parts = '132+456'.split('+');
parts[0]; //132
parts[1]; //456
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so

```js
var data = '132+456'.split('+');
var a = data[0];
var b = data[1];

// document.writeln only for example 
document.writeln(a);
document.writeln(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java

```
 String[] values='132+456'.split('+');
 String firstPart=value[0]; // has 132
```

for js

```
 var data = '132+456'.split('+');
 var a = data[0];
 var b = data[1];
```

Comment: question tagged as java script.

Comment: @AvinashRaj wrote for both of them ..As initially I thought java so wrote for both of them..